# Regular expression for considering one character in multiple groups

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to find all characters which are both preceded and followed by '+' sign.

Eg: For input

```
+z+45+v89+b+
```

I am expecting two groups i.e `+z+` and `+b+`.

I have written following regular expression in java which works for the above input

```
\\+[a-zA-Z]\\+
```

but fails for following input

```
+a+b+c+
```

For second input, I am expecting following groups `+a+` , `+b+`  and `+c+`

Comment: try thus [`String text = "+a+b+c+";

String regex = "(?=(\\+[a-zA-Z]\\+))";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}`](https://ideone.com/1VlQvv)

Comment: Thanks it works.

Comment: Just wondering why we need to capture first group as in matcher.group(1)? If i use matcher.group(), i don't get desired result.

Comment: because group(1) is represented by `(\\+[a-zA-Z]\\+)` and you have to capture that group, hope you get me?

Comment: Yes, got your point.